# Connect to SAP BW via Open Hub with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, sap-bw

I’m trying to load SAP BW data into Azure Data Lake with ADF, I have:

- Installed Self-hosted IR (using my laptop for testing purpose)
- Installed SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.0

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-sap-bw-data.

Discussed with someone from SAP team and stuck on setting up the RFC:

- Authorization for Remote Function Calls (RFC) and SAP BW.

I have setup a linked service in ADF (with all creds) and got this error:

> Get or create destination CLIENT=;SYSNR=;ASHOST= failed.
>
> LOCATION CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host WIN-NXOLX5J0FI with Unicode ERROR partner '' not reached TIME Wed May 20 10:38:42 2020
> RELEASE 721 COMPONENT NI (network interface) VERSION 40 RC -10 MODULE nixxi.cpp LINE 3289 DETAIL NiPConnect2:  SYSTEM CALL connect ERRNO 10060 ERRNO TEXT WSAETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out COUNTER 2 RETURN CODE: 20 Activity ID: a969876f-cddd-4626-ae2c-5c529f8ae6d9.

Any suggestions are welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: This appears to be connection issue that SAP system cannot be reached. You need to verify the connection in ADF portal first to see if it indeed sees your SAP through self-hosted IR. However, the bigger issue is OHS with third party tool (in this case, ADF) is not a robust interface because if your DTP fails, it's very difficult for external tool to know that and "reset" the status automatically. Perf is another issue as OHS has to use internal DB as staging first. https://www.aecorsoft.com/blog/2019/1/31/use-adf-and-ssis-to-copy-data-from-sap-bw-the-comparison-of-options

Comment: Thank you AecorSoft, will verify the connection in ADF! and noted your comments on the other issues.